Why can't use expression as argument in vba's vlookup function?
Sub id()
Debug.Print Left(Cells(2, 3), 6)
End Sub

It print 1234 in current window.
Sub id()
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(1234, Range("k:l"), 2, False)
End Sub

It print xxxx in the current window.
It encounter VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error".
Sub id()
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(Cells(2, 3), 6), Range("k:l"), 2, False)
End Sub

Why can't use expression as argument in vba's vlookup function?

You certainly can, you just have to remember that LEFT returns a string so you cannot use it if you are looking up a numerical value:
Your code worked perfectly well with a string input:

Works perfectly well with numerical inputs too:

And just to make sure:


Good work - just use Val or CLng or for type conversion, so that it's an explicit conversion, not * 1 which uses an implicit conversion.
